# How to detect when a folder change is completed?

Tags: delphi, tthread, readdirectorychangesw

I'm using Delphi and `ReadDirectoryChangesW` (in a `TThread`) to detect when a particular folder has changes. This is working quite nicely. I need to know when the changes are *done* so I can then safely do something with the file.

Here's the scenario: I've mapped a printer to a specific file name and folder (FILE: local port `c:\MonitorMe\prinfil.dat`). The only file in the folder will be that printer file. The print job can be single page, or hundreds of pages - and I have to wait until the "print to file" is complete before triggering further action. I'm monitoring `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE` and `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE` - so I will get periodic notices that the file is still "being printed to".

I'm looking for a safe way to actually detect when the "print" is complete. I thought I might set a timer up in the form, and call `Synchronize(StillPrinting)` in the thread. `StillPrinting` would stop and restart the timer such that only after some 300 ms of NO folder changes would the timer execute - triggering an `OnAfterPrintComplete` event. That just seems dangerous.

Is there anything I can look for to determine if the file save has been completed?

Comment: @fpiette In fact, that's it - when I read the ms docs for FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE flag, I interpreted it as "every write" (last time it wrote, multiple writes per save). It actually means "last write as file is closed" - exactly what I want. I saved a 1300 page file, and it did what I needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

"File has been completed" is subjective - just think about it for 5 minutes and you'll come to the conclusion you're asking for something that rarely makes sense:

- **Speed** of writing can vary: you might expect a file to be written in 2 seconds on one system while it takes 5 minutes on another.
- Drawing the line: at which point do you consider a "write" to be completed and at which point are other writes **appending to the existing** file? Thing about logs where it can take i.e. 2 years until another write to that file occurs. Likewise your printer job/program can idle for 10 minutes for whatever reason but still access the file.
- Modifications: what about a file that has been written from byte 1 to 52000 but afterwards bytes 10 to 19 are **overwritten**? When is that considered "completed"?
- Even [SetEndOfFile()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setendoffile) only "cuts" (or extends) a file at a given point, but nobody knows if additional writes **at any position** will occur.

No. But there are various approaches to achieve the same:

- Setting **file attributes**, i.e. `R` could signal that no more writes will occur. Because you as a consumer only want read access anyway. Of course, the "printer" has to set it.
- Inspecting the file content for a **valid footer**, or if any of its format seems to be incomplete. This both requires you to know the print file format and the print file to have a format at all (instead of just being a binary stream).
- Trying to open the file **without any sharing permission** (not even `FILE_SHARE_READ`) - this should fail as long as another process accesses the file. You can expect the printer job to not open/close the file multiple times (although that's a possibility, too).
- Abusing files as "writing complete" markers: if the file has been written, create another (empty) file whose **existence alone** signals that the other file is complete. As per your print job/program you could add another short/simple print task and judge that as soon as 2 files exist the one of interest must be completed (while the other is irrelevant to you).

Comment: thanks for the comments - in this particular case, there is only one process writing to that particular file. It's a program printing shipping labels - I'm looking to replace the built-in label format with my own format (I can determine the actual data to print from a sql query).  I have nothing but the print file to work with - I'm thinking maybe using FindFirstChangeNotificationW instead - when I see a change on the print file, then loop every 200ms checking to see if file can be opened.